# How is path parameter name conflicts handled in react-router-dom?

Tags: reactjs, url, react-router, react-router-dom, path-parameter

```
home/user/:id/friends/:id
```

```
function SomeComponent() {
  const { id } = useParams();
}
```

Which `id` will be used here? There are name conflicts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last parameter of the path is the value that any component will see.

This is trivial to test.

Example:

```
const Component = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();

  return <h1>Id: {id}</h1>;
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Link to="/home/user/123/friends/456">Test?</Link>

      <Routes>
        <Route path="home/user/:id/friends/:id" element={<Component />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit how-is-path-parameter-name-conflicts-handled-in-react-router-dom]

[image]

Don't use the same path parameter twice in the same path string per route.